# PrintQueue is the printer the default printer?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printqueue

I'm making my own dialog for printing in my application, now I have this code to put all the printers in a combobox:

```
        PrintServer server = new PrintServer();

        foreach (PrintQueue queue in server.GetPrintQueues())
        {
            cboPrinters.Items.Add(queue.FullName);
        }
```

However, I would need select the default printer, how can I see which one is the default printer?

Answer (score 3):

```
var DefaultPrinter = new LocalPrintServer().DefaultPrintQueue;
```